# Safari doesn't remember tabs in Mountain Lion

Tags: safari, macos, tabs

In Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Safari preserved the state of my tabs when it closed. This functionality seems to have disappeared in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. Is there a way to restore (no pun intended) this feature from with the System Preferences or perhaps a Terminal trick?

Comment: If you have *not* enabled *Close windows when quitting an application* under *System Preferences > General*, Safari reopens all tabs and windows.

Comment: I haven't touched any settings. Edit: It was enabled by default.

Comment: §$%&""§! Do you want me to answer still or will you just remove the question?

Comment: Answer it please. For future Googlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Undo quitting of all applications

Apple has slightly changed the wording but the location for this setting is still the same as in Lion:

*System Preferences → General → Close windows when quitting an application*

### Undo quitting for a specific application

This works only with *Close windows when quitting an application* disabled at the same time.

Type the following command in the Terminal. Then restart the specific application.

In general the syntax is:

```
defaults write com."producer"."program-name" ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

Thus, in your case (Safari.app) it is:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

You can undo this by using the parameter `NO` instead.

If you prefer a graphical interface, you can use [**TinkerTool**](http://bresink.de/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php5). But the current version 4.9 only supports the toggling on a per app basis in Lion. I'll update this answer when TinkerTool adds this feature for Mountain Lion as well.

Comment: So I *can* use the Terminal to enable this while leaving the setting in System Preferences as it was?

Comment: Not really, it only works the other way around. Will edit.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The function is disabled in the preferences, but safari still doesn't remember my tabs. When i quit and re-launch, a new window opens, not even in full-screen mode (Which i usually use). I even tried using the terminal command like you said, in the correct way. Help?

Comment: @Sherwin  
I can't really help with that. It's working for me... all I can say is to carefully read the answer again. I tested this in Safari on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the "Close windows when quitting an application" setting disabled, but certain apps don't restore their windows (while most other apps do), this fix worked for me:

1. Open System Preferences -> General, and *check* the "Close windows…" setting.
2. Close System Preferences
3. Reopen System Preferences -> General, *uncheck* the same setting, and close it again.

The setting should now be applied uniformly across all apps. At the very least, this fixed the issue where Safari would not restore its windows (even though other apps were doing so). (In my case, back in Lion I disabled window restoring on a few specific apps with the hidden setting via Terminal; Safari may have been one of them.)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check the `NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows` setting:

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows
defaults read com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows
```

The default behaviour should be a "does not exist" error, but if either is set to `0` Safari will not remember open tabs.

You can restore the default setting with:

```
defaults delete .GlobalPreferences NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows
defaults delete com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows
```